# How to fix this JBoss 6.2 EAP Deployment error about child container with name default already exists?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I am trying to deploy an application bundled as war to a JBoss EAP 6.2 server but I am getting the following error:

```
17:25:38,727 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) JBAS018210: Register web context: /tmt
17:25:38,745 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) JBWEB001097: Error starting context /tmt: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBWEB000250: Child container with name default already exists
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:794) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:785) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addChild(StandardContext.java:1862) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.JBossContextConfig.processWebMetaData(JBossContextConfig.java:471) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.JBossContextConfig.applicationWebConfig(JBossContextConfig.java:201) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.start(ContextConfig.java:354) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:153) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.JBossContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(JBossContextConfig.java:194) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:115) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3717) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)

17:25:38,747 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) JBWEB001103: Error detected during context /tmt start, will stop it
17:25:38,750 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./tmt: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./tmt: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:161)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93)
    ... 6 more

17:25:39,010 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 4) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "examples-simulated-2.1.0.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./tmt" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./tmt: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}
17:25:39,085 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment examples-simulated-2.1.0.war (runtime-name: examples-simulated-2.1.0.war) in 75ms
```

Any ideas guys?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have any other applications deployed, it looks like you have more than one app trying to bind to the same url context

Answer (score 0):

Check if "default" servlet is defined in web.xml.

Comment this->

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
<init-param>
  <param-name>useFileMappedBuffer</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
```